# Overlay makes truly a service last longer (killed by the system)?

Tags: java, android, service, overlay

I have an app with a service that run in the foreground and perform some tasks.
I believe whenever the system detect there is little memory available it kills my service.

When I was starting to develop for android back in 2019, few people were using overlay permissions in order to draw basically a dummy bubblehead or dummy pixel so that the service in foreground would last longer (less prone to be killed too much soon by the system).
I am wondering if there is any truth in this "workaround".

Also, by looking at the logcat I've noticed that the service is almost always killed when it's waiting, meaning during the invocation of `Thread.sleep()`.
Is that merely a coincidence or is it something that I could address?